# Variable not loaded the first time I try to use it. And only accessible the second time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform, ionic-framework

I have an angular.js / ionic framework app. That loads recipes in a list and allows the user to save any recipe they want. The problem is that the first time someone clicks save, nothing happens but on the second time onwards, the recipe is actually saved. This is because the variable is not loaded the first time someone clicks save and it is only loaded after the first click is made. How can I fix my code to get it to save the first time I click save?

Here is what my html looks like:

```
<ion-content has-header="true" padding="true" overflow-scroll="true">
    <input type="text" ng-model="searchString" placeholder="Search using recipe title ..." />
    <ion-list can-swipe="true">
        <ion-item class="item item-thumbnail-left" ng-repeat="recipeItem in remoteRecipeList| searchFor:searchString" type="item-text-wrap"
                  href="#/tab/browse/{{recipeItem.id}}">
            <img ng-src="{{recipeItem.get('picture').url()}}">
            <div><strong>{{recipeItem.get('title')}}</strong></div>
            <div class="">{{recipeItem.get('description')}}</div>
            <ion-option-button class="button-balanced" ng-click="doSaveRow(recipeItem.id)">
                Save
            </ion-option-button>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

And here is what my controller (javascript) looks like:

```
.controller('BrowseCtrl', function (user, $state, $scope, RecipeService, $cordovaCamera, $ionicPopup, $timeout, ParseRecipeService, ParseConfiguration, UserService, $cordovaSQLite) {

    $scope.count = 0;

    // if not using parse then assign the image service to the default
    // service
    if (ParseConfiguration.USING_PARSE === false) {
        ParseRecipeService = RecipeService;
        console.log("ParseConfiguration: " + ParseConfiguration.USING_PARSE);
    }

    ParseRecipeService.all().then(function (_data) {

        $timeout($scope.remoteRecipeList = _data, 0);

        console.log(JSON.stringify(_data));
    }, function (_error) {
        console.error(JSON.stringify(_error));
        alert(_error.message)
    });

    // Save the selected recipe to SQL database
    $scope.doSaveRow = function (_index) {

        $scope.count++;


        ParseRecipeService.get(_index).then(function (_data) {
            $timeout($scope.recipeItem = _data, 0);
        }, function (_error) {
            console.error(_error.message);                
        });

        var query = "INSERT INTO recipetable (id, instructions, title, description, num_serves, recipe_type, time_in_minutes, picture, ingredients) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, [null,  $scope.recipeItem.get('instructions'), $scope.recipeItem.get('title'), $scope.recipeItem.get('description'), $scope.recipeItem.get('num_serves'), $scope.recipeItem.get('recipe_type'), $scope.recipeItem.get('time_in_minutes'), $scope.recipeItem.get('picture').url(), $scope.recipeItem.get('ingredients')]).then(function(res) {
            alert("The recipe has been saved to your device");
        }, function (err) {
            console.error(err);
        });

        $scope.searchTitles = true;
          $scope.searchDescriptions = true;

          $scope.$watch('searchTitles', function(){
            $scope.searchKeys = [ $scope.searchTitles ? 'title' : null, $scope.searchDescriptions ? 'description' : null ];
          });
          $scope.$watch('searchTitles', function(){
            $scope.searchKeys = [ $scope.searchTitles ? 'title' : null, $scope.searchDescriptions ? 'description' : null ];
          });

    };            
})
```

Comment: It looks like you're missing code in your example `doSaveRow` method.

Comment: I've added the missing code. I had removed to make things simpler

Comment: "this is because the variable is not loaded the first time...."  *which* variable isn't loaded?  and I agree with the other comment; you already have the item; don't pass only the id and then perform an unnecessary lookup...

Comment: why not passing the whole recipeItem to doSaveRow?

Comment: also, there seem to be multiple places where you are using `$timeout` for some unknown reason.  that assignment `$scope.recipeItem = _data` certainly doesn't need to be wrapped in a `$timeout`.

Comment: Agree with @Claies about the use of $timeout. Also, how do you know it saves the second time, but not the first? What variable isn't loaded?